# EFI lock on 2015 MacBook Air

Tags: macbook

About a month ago, my computer was taken from the library. Two weeks later, for some odd reason, it was turned back in.

We did put an iCloud lock on with a 4 digit passcode. Unfortunately, now that we have the computer back, we forgot the passcode and we have to wait 60 minutes to try each time.

When we went into the Apple Store we were told that they need the original purchase receipt in order to unlock the firmware lock. We never had the original receipt as we bought it from eBay and the 6 month buyer protection is up by one month...

The young man at the Apple Store told me that if I replace the SSD it would solve the issue. Is that correct? Is that the only solution?

Thanks for your help!
Chris

Comment: Changing hardware [will not neccesseraly work](https://www.cnet.com/au/news/efi-firmware-protection-locks-down-newer-macs/). Was this Mac associated with your Apple ID?

Comment: It was associated to my Apple ID. And I did read something similar which is why I questioned what I was told. Do you know if it could work if my Apple ID was associated?

Comment: Make sure that this EFI locked mac is [listed under the assosiated devices](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205064) on your Apple ID and give your local Apple store a visit again. Btw, you still should have the eBay purchase history bring it along it might help proving that you bought this device.

Comment: It is listed under my devices and I showed that along with the eBay purchase list and PayPal receipt. On top of it i showed them the text conversations i had with the seller and that the claim I started through PayPal was denied in my favor.